# How to send data from localhost to server using Python requests?

Tags: python, django, localhost, remote-server

I am trying to send data from localhost to an API in remote server using Python Requests & Django through an API: `/api/send-data/`

Path for `/api/send-data/` in urls.py is  `path('send-data/',view_send_data.send_data,name='send_data')`

This is my `view_send_data.py` in my localhost:

```
@api_view(('POST',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
def send_data():


        # defining the API-endpoint  
        API_ENDPOINT = "http://68.183.89.234/api/screen/"

        # data to be sent to API
        data = {'data':1234} 

        # sending post request and saving response as response object 
        r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data) 
        print(r.json())

        return Response({"success": True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Path for api at `http://68.183.89.234/api/screen/` in urls.py is `path('screen/',views_fr.screen_display,name='screen')`

This is my `views_fr.py` in my remote server:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def screen_display(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

         return Response({"success": True,
                                     "response": request.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I call `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/send-data/"` in my browser, I am getting `405 Method Not Allowed`

Is this the correct way to do it or am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because the remote server API only accepts POST method, but you can't make a POST request using the browser url call. Test the API using postman or curl so you can set the correct method for request.